# Sum of zeros and ones in a Binary De-Bruijn sequence

Tags: algorithm, binary

I need to prove/ disapprove whether in every binary De-Bruijn sequence there is equal amount of zeros and ones. 
From several examples I did with n=3 and n=2 I saw that there is the same amount of 0s and 1s in the sequence but I don't really know why.. I don't know how to relate it to the De-Bruijn seq. rules

Answer (score 0):

A De-Bruijn sequence B(k, n) is constructed by a Hamiltonian path of an n-dimensional De-Bruijn graph over k symbols. Equivalently, an Eulerian cycle of a (n-1)-dimensional De-Bruijn graph.

We examine B(2, n).

Lemma: Every De-Bruijn graph is Eulerian.
DB(n) is balanced. This is because we can take any vertex, which is a sequence of length (n − 1), and delete the last digit, then add a 0 or 1 in front, giving us that in-degree = 2 for each vertex. Similarly we obtain that out-degree = 2 for each vertex. Since all vertices have an even degree, via Euler, there is an Eulerian cycle of the graph.

We construct B(2, n) by performing the cycle starting from any vertex, adding the corresponding bits/symbols which was shifted in as we traverse each edge.

Hypothesis: the number of 1 bits in DB(2, n) is equal to the number of 0 bits.

We noted above the out-degree for each vertex in the graph equals two. This means, that for every vertex, we must have recorded a 1 and a 0 in the sequence. Equivalently, we record an equal amount of 1 and 0 in the sequence.

Since an Eulerian cycle uses an edge exactly once, and visits a vertex exactly k=2 times, it follows the number of 1 bits in DB(2, n) is equal to the number of 0 bits.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, each possible string of *n* bits occurs exactly once. This means that each possible string of *n*−1 bits occurs exactly twice: once after a zero, once after a one. There are 2<sup>*n*−1</sup> such strings. Therefore, there are exactly 2<sup>*n*−1</sup> zeroes and exactly 2<sup>*n*−1</sup> ones.

Comment: Good solution! Deleted my clumsy solution after reading yours.

Comment: Thanks :) when you say string, do you mean a string in the sequence?

Comment: @xYaelx: No, I don't. But since the sequence, by definition, includes every string, I suppose it doesn't make that much difference.

Comment: This is circular reasoning. The definition of DB sequences says every possible length-n string on A occurs exactly once as a substring, from which your opening statement (eventually) follows.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: My opening statement does not "(eventually) follow" from your definition; rather, it *is* your definition (with A = {0, 1}). What difference do you perceive?